# getParent Object from Array / Knockout / mapping.Plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Have a look on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kirtapatrik/LwBvc/ 
Why i don't get the parent object, if the child is a array?

Thx for support
Patrik

Comment: Knockout Mapping plugin v2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the "parent" object because you are rendering an observable array item.  The parent of an observable array item is the observable array itself.

This works just as the documentation states: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

> parent: The parent object or array to which this child belongs